# ckeditor: "a is undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I just added CKEditor to my website, but I'm getting the following error in my console:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/p4c3J4E.png]

I followed the [installation guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_installation) as it's written so I have no idea what's wrong.

Here's, briefly, what my call looks like:

```
<textarea id="full-editor" name="full-editor" rows="10" columns="6"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('#full-editor');
</script>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using?.. It seems prolly your browser is not compatible with CKEditor

Comment: @user3769178 just answered your question below. Hope it helps

Answer (score 12):

Aah.. try this

Remove `#` from the selector inside `CKEDITOR.replace('#full-editor');`

According to installation guide you shared, this is what u need

```
CKEDITOR.replace('full-editor'); // NO #. You must have got confused with jQuery
```

Comment: I have used as mentioned but I am getting another issue. TypeError: c[a] is undefined

Answer (score 6):

This also happened whenever we put initializer script before `<textarea>`.

Ensure to put

```
<script>
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
</script>
```

before the `</body>` tag (i.e. closing body tag).

Answer (score 1):

`<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('#full-editor');
</script>`

Please add above code in external js file and include this js in html page after title page like

```
$(document).ready(function () {// save as  like ckEditorInclude.js
  CKEDITOR.replace('#full-editor');
}
<script src="Your folder path/ckEditorInclude.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This also happened whenever we put initializer script before .
Ensure to put

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
```

before the `</body>` tag (i.e. closing body tag).

Answer (score 1):

This append to me because i was trying to use CKEDITOR.replace("editor") but there was no element in dom with Id or name "editor"

Answer (score 1):

The issue for me was I copied the code locally from the cdn so that I can work on it if I am not online. I am using version 4.9.2 standard.
Examining  the chrome console  gave several 404 errors which were not obvious using FireFox.  Reverting back to the cdn resolved the issue.
Unfortunately, no working offline with this it seems at least not for this version of ckeditor.