# Replace config attribute in CKEditor 4.10: a is undefined

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Having a instance of CKEditor in some proprietary third party app, I want to replace some config parameters for customization purpose. For example, some toolbar buttons are removed by refault, I want to make all visible.

I tried different things like

```
var instance = CKEDITOR.instances['editor2']
instance.config.removeButtons = ""
instance.destroy()
CKEDITOR.replace('editor2')
```

which I found [here](https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/Support/Modify-CKEDITOR.config-in-browser-and-allpy-the-changes), but got always the following error:

> TypeError: a is undefined

Found some SO queststions where this is related to a leading # in the Id, but i dont have it and the instance exists when looking into the instances with browser developer tools:

```
> CKEDITOR.instances
Object { editor1: {…}, editor2: {…} }
```

Also tried the following Id of the object instead of `editor2`

```
> CKEDITOR.instances.editor2.id
"cke_54"
```

Or [use replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597939/ckeditor-a-is-undefined):

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor2', {removeButtons: ''})
```

But all of this doesn't work too, I always get the same error that a is undefined. The editor itself works and doesn't throw any errors in the browser console.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error:

> TypeError: a is undefined

I traced my issue to the element not being found. Specifically for me, my document had not fully loaded when my JS code, similar to yours, was run.

I would investigate two things:

1. Ensure there is an element in your document with the ID='editor2'.
2. Don't run your JS until the document is ready. Do this by wrapping it in $( document ).ready(). Example:

   $( document ).ready(function() {
       var instance = CKEDITOR.instances['editor2']
       instance.config.removeButtons = ""
       instance.destroy()
       CKEDITOR.replace('editor2')
   });